# Problem with the order of references in the bibliography using ieeetr.bst

Tags: bibliographies, bibliographystyle

Compiler: XeLaTeX

I have a file `Bibliography.bib` with the following code included:

```
@misc{Bacterial_Classification,
    author = "Franklin D. Lowy",
    title = "Bacterial Classification, Structure and Function",
    howpublished = {\url{https://api.semanticscholar.org/CorpusID:49963607 (accessed: Columbia University, 2008)}},
    keywords = "Basics of Bacteria"
}

@article{Mass_Spectrometry,
  author =       "Anja Freiwald
and Sacsha Sauer",
  title =        "Phylogenetic classification and identification of bacteria by mass spectrometry",
  journal =      "Nat Protoc",
  volume =       "4",
  number =       "5",
  pages =        "732-742",
  year =         "2009, doi: https://doi.org/10.1038/nprot.2009.37",
  DOI =          "https://doi.org/10.1038/nprot.2009.37",
  keywords =     "Spectrometry"
}
```

In my `main.tex` file in the end which I want the bibliography to go I have the following code:

```
\pagestyle{plain}
\nocite{*}
\bibliographystyle{ieeetr}

\renewcommand{\refname}{REFERENCES}
\phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{REFERENCES}
\bibliography{Bibliography.bib}
\clearpage
```

So, I have written for IEEE style, correct? In IEEE style references appear in the order citations are mentioned in the text of the document. "*Reference list entries should appear in the order the sources are cited in the text of the paper, beginning with [1], and continuing in the ascending numerical order, from the lowest number to the highest. Reference list entries do not follow an alphabetical order by author or title of sources.*"

I mention `Bacterial_Classification` *first* as `\cite{Bacterial_Classification}` and *then* I mention Mass_Spectrometry as `\cite{Mass_Spectrometry}` BUT in the resulting output on pdf, in the last section which references are, they appearing like this:

> [1] A. Freiwald and S. Sauer, “Phylogenetic classification and identification of bacteria by mass spectrometry,” Nat Protoc, vol. 4, no. 5, pp. 732–742, 2009, doi: https://doi.org/10.1038/nprot.2009.37.
>
> [2] F. D. Lowy, “Bacterial classification, structure and function.” https://api.semanticscholar.org/
> CorpusID:49963607(accessed:ColumbiaUniversity,2008).

If I delete the citation of `Mass_Spectrometry` (`\cite{Mass_Spectrometry}`) of course the reference will go second (because 1) that is the order in the `.bib` file and 2) I have a citation of `Bacterial_Classification` either way), *but* if I cite it again (I am repeating *after* the citation of `Bacterial_classification`) it will once again go first …

Why exactly is this happening and the 2nd mentioned citation is appearing first with number [1] at the text too, while the 1st mentioned citation is appearing second with number [2] at the text.
How can I solve this?

PS: Literally if I create a new document with *exactly* the same preamble it will fix the problem … I am going to lose my mind. Is something in my text causing the problem? How could it be? It is not code … I literally just created a new document with copy/paste the same preamble and I only wrote the bibliography code in the `\begin{document} \end{document}` phase.

PS2: (EDITED) I just found that the problem is I have many `.tex` files. I mean that I have my main but the I have `.tex` file for each of my chapters. So when I cite a bibliography in the other `.tex` files and not in the main, the references are appearing *only* by alphabetic order.

How to I fix this? What must I include in my code and where?

Comment: The `ieeetr` bibliography style is one of the original BibTeX styles (along with stalwarts such as `plain`, `abbrv`, `unsrt`, `alpha`, and `apalike`) and, as such, hasn't been modified meaningfully in more than 35 [!] years. If you want current IEEE style, please use `IEEEtran.bst`.

Comment: @Mico 1) You mean \bibliographystyle{IEEEtran.bst} instead of \bibliographystyle{ieeetr}? That is useful, obviously I want the current IEEE style. But when I am typing it it does not appear the coomand automatically like it does with ieeetr. Why isa that?

Comment: 2) It does not solve my problem though.

Comment: I found the problem and I explain it on P.S. 2 but I can not figure how to solve it.

Comment: The proper syntax is `\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}`, *not* `\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran.bst}`. For sure, after changing the argument of `\bibliographystyle`, one *must* run a full recompile cycle -- LaTeX, BibTeX, and LaTeX twice more -- to fully propagate all changes. I'm afraid I have no idea what "But when I am typing it it does not appear the coomand automatically like it does with ieeetr" is supposed to mean.

Comment: Okey, thank you! I changed it correctly this time. Do not worry for the automatic typesetting I wrote. As for the changes, I recompiled it many times now, it does not change the order of the references. I found that it will do it properly only if I cite something in the main.tex file which I include the code for the bibliography of course. If I cite something in the otehr .tex files it won't. I am "calling" the other files in the main.tex file like that: \section{Electronic Biosensor}
\input{Chapter 4}

Comment: It sounds like you're not setting up the per-chapter bibliographies correctly. Feel free to post a new query, in which you (a) describe your document setup more precisely (and also provide some much-needed information, such as the document class that's in use) and (b) ask how you might set up per-chapter bibliographies correctly.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/149974/discussion-between-dguys-and-mico).

Comment: Please see the answer I just posted.

Comment: Off-topic: Just so that the typo at the end is not also contained in the final document, I would like to point out that it should read "Sascha Sauer" instead of "Sacsha Sauer".

Comment: @cabohah You are right, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Please do yourself a big favor and stop using the grossly out of date `ieeetr` bibliography style. If, instead, you use the `IEEEtran` bibliography style, the bibliographic entries will be sorted by order of their appearance in the `\cite` commands in the body of the document.

[image]

In the code below, note that I've replaced

```
howpublished = {\url{https://api.semanticscholar.org/CorpusID:49963607 (accessed: Columbia University, 2008)}},
```

with

```
  url      = "https://api.semanticscholar.org/CorpusID:49963607",
  year     = 2008,
  note     = "Accessed: Columbia University",
```

I.e., the `IEEEtran` bib style knows about a field called `url`.

---

```
% !TEX TS-program = xelatex
\documentclass{article}

\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{Bibliography.bib}
@misc{Bacterial_Classification,
  author   = "Franklin D. Lowy",
  title    = "Bacterial Classification, Structure and Function",
  url      = "https://api.semanticscholar.org/CorpusID:49963607",
  year     = 2008,
  note     = "Accessed: Columbia University",
  keywords = "Basics of Bacteria"
}
@article{Mass_Spectrometry,
  author   = "Anja Freiwald and Sascha Sauer",
  title    = "Phylogenetic classification and identification of bacteria by mass spectrometry",
  journal  = "Nat Protoc",
  volume   = "4",
  number   = "5",
  pages    = "732-742",
  year     = "2009",
  url      = "https://doi.org/10.1038/nprot.2009.37",
  keywords = "Spectrometry"
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage{cite} % classic citation management package for numeric citation call-outs
\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran} % <-- not 'ieeetr', please
\usepackage{xurl} % allow line breaks at arbitrary points in a URL string

\begin{document}
\noindent
\cite{Bacterial_Classification}, \cite{Mass_Spectrometry}
\bibliography{Bibliography}
\end{document}
```

Comment: 1) Thank you for the useful information! Really, the appearance of bibliography is much better now. 2) I see that I also can use online now instead of misc. Is this more appropriate? Because before I could not use online, I assume it was because of "ieeetr". 3) Finally, it did not solve the problem with the order. You mentioned something about set up per chapter bibliography. What exactly should I include?

Comment: @DGuys - About 2): The `@online` entry type is an alias for the `@electronic` entry type. The file `IEEEtran.bst` has the following to say about the `@electronic` entry type: "the @electronic entry types use periods as inter-item punctuation rather than the commas used by the other entry types; and URLs are never followed by periods even though they are the last item in the entry". Whether this is more or less appropriate is not for me to decide. About 3): Please post a new query. Do you maybe have multiple `\bibliographystyle` directives in your tex file(s)? If so, only the first one counts.

Comment: 2) Thank you for that!! 3) No, I do not have multiple \bibliographystyle. I will ppst a new query and I will let you know.

Comment: I just posted a new query for this, if you could please answer there. I think that I found where the problem appears but I do not know why or how to fix it.